# options_for_select (multiple true) just click to select multiple options instead of having to hold down shift or command for multiple selections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm using the `options_for_select` tag with `{ :multiple => true }` set. If a user wants to select multiple options they have to hold down shift or command (for mac), to select multiple options. Can I have it set so the user can simply click on the options they want and it will select the options they click, and click again on a selected option to deselect it? I don't want to tell users to hold down command to select multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it that way for select tag.

As stated in W3 School http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Selecting multiple options vary in different operating systems and browsers:

**For windows**: 
Hold down the control (ctrl) button to select multiple options

**For Mac**: Hold down the command button to select multiple options

Because of the different ways of doing this, and because **you have to inform the user that multiple selection is available**, it is more user-friendly to use checkboxes instead.

Unless you will build a hard-coded jquery for that function.

Comment: Thanks might use checkboxes. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else as a solution. Even if it be jquery.